# onBindViewHolder always triggers when opening dialog in fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have issues on onbindviewholder of my recyclerview while opening or closing a dialog in fragment. it always triggers `onbindviewholder` even if I don't call notifychanges for adapter.

has any one experience this? either using callbacks or `Fragment.MyFunction()` to call from adapter to fragment, still triggering `onbindviewholder`.

**my adapter:**

```
     public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    ....
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_product_extruck2,
                parent, false);
        final ViewHolder holder1 = new ViewHolder(v);
        return holder1;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.priceTxt.setText("0.00");
        holder.lin_product_info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyFragment.showdialog(list.get(position),position);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() { return list.size(); }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }
    @Override
    public void setHasStableIds(boolean hasStableIds) {
        super.setHasStableIds(false);
    }
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.lin_product_info) LinearLayout lin_product_info;
        @BindView(R.id.price) TextView priceTxt;
        @BindView(R.id.itemCode) TextView itemCodeTxt;
        @BindView(R.id.productName) TextView productNameTxt;
        @BindView(R.id.img) ImageView img;
        @BindView(R.id.inventory_item_layout) LinearLayout inventory_item_layout;

        public ViewHolder(final View convertView) {
            super(convertView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this,convertView);
            convertView.setTag(this);
        }
    }
    // adding new items add in que
    void updateItemsInternal(final List<Inventory> newItems) {
        final List<Inventory> oldItems = new ArrayList<>(this.list);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(">>", "run thread updatesinternal "+newItems.size());
                final DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult =
                        DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new DiffInventory(oldItems, newItems));
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d(">>", "run thread updatesinternal handler");
                        applyDiffResult(newItems, diffResult);
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }
    // This method is called when the background work is done
    protected void applyDiffResult(List<Inventory> newItems,
                                   DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult) {
        pendingUpdates.remove(newItems);
        if (pendingUpdates.size() > 0) {
            List<Inventory> latest = pendingUpdates.pop();
            pendingUpdates.clear();
            updateItemsInternal(latest);
        }
        dispatchUpdates(newItems, diffResult);
    }
    // updating and notifying adapter
    protected void dispatchUpdates(List<Inventory> newItems,
                                   DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult) {
        this.list = newItems;
        diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
    }
}
```

I use diffutil for adding items on adapter `(updateItems())`

**fragment :**

```
    public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
    ....
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        cache = Cache.getInstance(getActivity());
        dbH = new DBHelper(getActivity());
        mContext = getContext();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sales_entry, container, false);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        mContext = getContext();
        inventoryListAdapter = new MyAdapter (getContext(), this,
                    new ArrayList<Inventory>(), pageFlag);
        inventoryListAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(inventoryListAdapter);

        //add sample items 
        inventoryListAdapter.updateItems(arr_inv);

    }

    public static void showdialog(Inventory inv, final int pos){
        final Inventory inventory = inv;
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_price_adjustment);
        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_confirm);
        final EditText et_orig_price = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.et_orig_price);
        final EditText et_discount = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.et_discount);
        final TextView tv_item_total = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_total);

        String at = "0.00";
        tv_item_total.setText(at);
        et_orig_price.setText(inventory.getInvSrp(""));
        et_discount.setText(inventory.getDiscount());
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        et_orig_price.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(s.length() != 0) {
                    Double amt = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
                    String amount = formatMoney(amt);
                    tv_item_total.setText(amount);
                } else {
                    tv_item_total.setText("0.00");
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        et_discount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                et_orig_price.setText(formatMoney(s.toString()));
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your code also

Comment: Where have you put your code for opening and closing dialog? can you please share your code here